# Create a new Self Signed Certificate

Tags: single-sign-on

In our Org we have setup SSO with ADFS 2.0, we are using a Self-Signed Certificate which is about to expire in a couple of days.

In Certificate and key Management section I got an option to create a new Self-Signed certificate. But is it just create a new certificate a new certificate or is there any further procedure after creating a new  certificate?

Does this have any impact on current users?

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just create a Self-Signed Certificate from the Certificate and key Management section.

Upload the same certificate in Identity Provider Certificate & Upload the same certificate in the system which is used with Salesforce for SSO Authentication(in this case it was ADFS).